# Recommend a read

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations

I am new to this field and looking for novice books to buy on physics and quantum physics...Any introductory literature recommendation would be highly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: What's "new to the field"? Especially: what sort of mathematical background do you have?

Comment: If by "field" you mean physics in general, a good intro text is Halliday and Resnick: http://www.amazon.com/Physics-Volume-1-David-Halliday/dp/0471320579